# Show that $f^{-1}(U\cup V) = f^{-1}(U)\cup f^{-1}(V)$

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function from one set $X$ to another set $Y$, and let $U,V$ be subsets of $Y$. Show that

(a) $f^{-1}(U\cup V) = f^{-1}(U)\cup f^{-1}(V)$,

(b) $f^{-1}(U\cap V) = f^{-1}(U)\cap f^{-1}(V)$,

(c) $f^{-1}(U\backslash V) = f^{-1}(U)\backslash f^{-1}(V)$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

(a) According to the definition of inverse image, one has
\begin{align*}
x\in f^{-1}(U\cup V) & \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in U\cup V\\\\ & \Longleftrightarrow (f(x)\in U)\vee (f(x)\in V)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x\in f^{-1}(U))\vee(x\in f^{-1}(V))\\\\ & \Longleftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(U)\cup f^{-1}(V) 
\end{align*}

(b) Analogously, one has
\begin{align*}
x\in f^{-1}(U\cap V) & \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in U\cap V\\\\ & \Longleftrightarrow (f(x)\in U)\wedge(f(x)\in V)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x\in f^{-1}(U))\wedge(x\in f^{-1}(V))\\\\ & \Longleftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(U)\cap f^{-1}(V).
\end{align*}

(c) Finally, one has that
\begin{align*}
x\in f^{-1}(U\backslash V) & \Longleftrightarrow f(x)\in U\backslash V\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (f(x)\in U)\wedge(f(x)\not\in V)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x\in f^{-1}(U))\wedge(x\not\in f^{-1}(V))\\\\ & \Longleftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(U)\backslash f^{-1}(V).
\end{align*}

Could someone double-check my answer or provide any comments?

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Yes it's correct

Comment: Thanks for the feedback folks